# connection between one web-server one private server

Tags: php, http, curl, tcp, server

I have a web server and I want to make connection between a private server. The goal is to exchange data, while the two computer is keeping the connection.

I can't open port on the web server and I don't want to open one on the private server. So i can't use sockets. This is because I don't want the private server to be accessible to anyone on the internet. The best solution would look like the private server initiate the connection and then the web server accepts it and then the connection is established.(Because I can't open ports, I have to use port 80 on the web server side.)
So now some data can flow to both sides.

The big question: How can I manage this without opening any port (manually?)
I want to make this in PHP but if there something else that can solve this then that's okay too.

**EDIT**: I can't install any software (vpn, etc..) on the web server

Comment: why don't you just use Access control ? on a specific port say 8080 and allow connections only from web-server ?

Comment: If your private server has a static IP you could also just allow that IP access

Comment: That's a good idea. If I do that, let's say I only allow that IP address to access, then others from the internet could see the computer, just their packets would be dropped or they couldn't see it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add some information about what type of data you want to exchange between the two systems. And what you mean by "exchange" here.

In general it is very hard to initiate a connection between two systems when none of them is listening on some port. That does not have to be insecure, there are many ways to lock that down. Actually the system you call "web server" already has a port it is listening on, port 80. So indeed you can use that. However the http protocol typically spoken on that port is not first choice for many types if data exchange. That's why I asked for more details about that above.

I suspect you have some other means of access to both systems, since somehow you must be able to access them to install software and the like. Typically that is done by using `ssh`, the "secure shell". If you have such access (which actually also means one port is open and listened to, typically that is port 22), then you could use that for your exchange. If for example you want to synchronize data (file hierarchies), then the `rsync` protocol / utility is probably the best and easiest approach, since it can transfer data via a secure shell layer.

But as said above: to tell more you really need to add more details about what it is you want to do to your question.

**EDIT**: I can't install any software (vpn, etc..) on the web server

Comment: I can't install any software unfortunately neither vpn or ssh. The data would be some xml or plain text.
What I really want to send some piece of information (query parameter or something like that) and give that information to a PHP file which will do the query and then send back the answer.

Comment: @Alex Then how do you access the systems at all? I mean somehow you must place your php files there...

Comment: I don't have the actual server. I rent a website and i can upload files there. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: That is why I cant open a new port on the web server

Comment: And _how_ do you "upload" files, if you have no connection? Apparently you _do_ have some sort of connection... So why not use that? What kind of access do you have?

Comment: If you really want to do that by means of php, then two approaches are straight forward: first take a look at php based file managers, they usually also allow to transfer files. Just google for that, there are many solutions alike. Or you implement some script that accepts request parameters and does something with that. But you will have to be more specific about what you want to do, otherwise we cannot offer a more specific answer here.

Comment: Yes indeed I have a connection, but how could I use that? I want some automatic duty to be done. For example:

A client want some information (the client is on a webpage and the web server runs it) which can be find on the private server. If the private server could maintain a continuous connection then the web server could ask it for the information.

Comment: OK, it is a bit annoying that we have to drag every bit of information out of you... At least we now know that somehow someone queries that "web server" for some information which that in turn has to fetch from that "private server", which is not reachable by any means. Very strange setup. There is no easy approach for that, since it is out of range of all "usual" solutions. Typically one runs a http server on the "private system" for that, locks down access by ip address and maybe additional authentication steps and all is fine. Without that things are _really_ difficult.

Comment: The issue here is that http (which you claim is the only protocol available here) does not easily lend itself for such things. It is crafted for something else. possible approaches might be to miss use fuser mounts via http to transfer information entities on a file system level that is shared, but that is quite exotic. Or maybe you could use web sockets and somehow "turn them around", but there is no ready to use solution for that. and frankly, the effort for all that exceeds everything that makes sense. Install an http server on the "private system". That is what networking is for.

Comment: This was not an answer, a real answer is impossible with that vague and little information available. I just gave those hints I could. Hope you find a solution that suits you. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Private machine can do a "PUT/GET" over web-server to transfer file contents.